# How to launch a class function on promise in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following class:

```
let graphFactory = new GraphFactory();

function GraphFactory(){
    let value = 'something';
    this.release = function() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to call this function from another place in my program in this way:

```
let newvalue = graphFactory.release();
```

It does not recognize `graphFactory` because it takes some time to load this function.

I would like to resolve this by issuing a promise when `graphFactory` is fully loaded and activated, but when I tried to add a function into `GraphFactory` function like

```
function GraphFactory(){
    let value = 'something';
    this.release = function() {
        graphFactoryPromise(value);
    }
}
```

and then

```
function graphFactoryPromise() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            resolve('loaded');
     });
}
```

and calling it as

```
graphFactoryPromise().then(function(result) {
    let newvalue = result;
});
```

It still doesn't work (`graphFactory` is not recognized).

What would be a good solution to this?

**UPDATE** 
What I want is to be able to call the function `graphFactory.release()` only after `graphFactory` is defined and loaded.

Comment: "**it takes some time to load this function.*" - what exactly is loaded where? Nothing in the code you've shown is asynchronous

Comment: if the function takes the time it must have already a callback or a promise.

Comment: Please add the code that "*loads `graphFactory`*". It's still unclear what you are doing. Are you asynchronously loading the `value` *inside* the `GraphFactory`, or are you loading the entire module file, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `release()` as a promise:

```js
const graphFactory = new GraphFactory();

function GraphFactory() {
  this.value = 'Something';

  const graphFactoryPromise = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('new-Something'), 1000));

  // Release is a promise
  this.release = async () => {
    this.value = await graphFactoryPromise(); // New Result
    return this.value;
  };
}

console.log(graphFactory.value);
graphFactory.release().then(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you! But in fact is there any way to actually access the function `graphFactory.release()` but only after it is loaded?

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin I added a timeout, can you show an example of what you mean? What does it mean "access the function only after it is loaded"