# How to call a function from a class but only after it's populated with values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have a problem in that there are several functions and constructors spread out in the different parts of my script.

For instance, I have the following function, which generates the names for the nodes

```
let graphFactory = new GraphFactory();

function GraphFactory() {

     let nodeNames = ['apple', 'orange'];

     this.getNodeNames = function() {
         return nodeNames;
     }
}
```

However, this function is loaded after another script, which needs the value returned by `graphFactory.getNodeNames()`.

However, when I run

```
 let value = graphFactory.getNodeNames();
```

I obviously get an error, because `graphFactory` is declared later below and so it's not recognized. And even if it was, it's not guaranteed that the value I need would already be loaded.

How would I change all this to ensure:

1) `value` gets a value only after `nodeNames` in `graphFactory` is populated

2) That `graphFactory` is recognized even if it's declared later in the script?

As I understand I need to use promises, but even with the promises I don't quite get how I could structure this whole thing in the way that it would work?

I was also thinking to use `async/await` but I don't quite understand how to integrate it into my structure above.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you just wait for the script that defines and instantiates `graphFactory` to load, before trying to call it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance how would I wait for it?

Comment: Can you give the script that calls `let value = graphFactory.getNodeNames();` the `defer` attribute, giving other scripts a chance to load first?

Comment: Classes are not hoisted so you need to call it after it's defined as CP suggested.

Comment: Why don't you load the script that uses `graphFactory` after the script that creates `graphFactory`?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918703/how-to-launch-a-class-function-on-promise-in-javascript), or did you come to the conclusion that there is nothing asynchronous about your script and you're just calling things in the wrong order? If yes, please remove the promise and async tags from your question.

Comment: It works fine when you correct the order, I just tried it, there's absolutely no need for async await.

Comment: Can you please give feed-back on the comment from mgarica of 1 hour ago? Just swap the scripts.... And if that is not possible, please add the code in your question that demonstrates why.

Comment: @mgarcia yes I did that and it works, but I was wondering if this can be realized with promises. it would be great not to play tetris with my scripts but to just issue promises when things are loaded...

Comment: @Bergi well in fact this is a different way of explaining what I needed to do as the first question was more general and now it's getting more specific about promises and async

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin No, your question still is as unspecific as the old one. And again you haven't really shown us what is asynchronous in your code - my guess: nothing is, so you should not use promises. Instead of playing tetris, you should be using a module system that allows you to declare your modules' dependencies and let it sort out the load order.